# Ignore "missing" database while executing SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing an application that creates a SQL Server database for another program. For this I load a large SQL-script containing the `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE TABLE` and so on.

The first lines of the script is:

```
/*CREATE DATABASE*/
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [MultiRisk5] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
GO
USE [MultiRisk5]
GO
```

And the C# code:

```
var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("myConnection");
var cmd = new SqlCommand("mySqlScript", sqlConn);
sqlConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

When I run the program I get an exception on the `USE` statement that tells me that the database MultiRisk5 doesn't exist.

How can this be, when I just created the database? The script runs fine when executed in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL Server command. It is a batch separator for Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load a script in c# that has GO in it and run it.

GO is recognised the SQL Server client tools only, and as a batch separator. The database engine won't recognise it. See these questions for more on how to do this

- [Execute sql file on SQL Server using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4808129/27535)
- [Add column to table and then update it inside transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4443262/27535)

Also, does the SqlConnection try to connect to MultiRisk5? if so, this will error too before `USE master` is run

Comment: Wow. 2 downvotes now. One removed upvote. Some interesting voting patterns here

Comment: I'd added a +1, but -2 seems more like someone acting for motives other than valid scoring.

Comment: This is indubitably one of the errors they're encountering, so I've +1ed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try executing your query in a try catch block to see what comes back.  That would be a good first step into figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app does not have the appropriate rights to create the database ?
You should check whether the database creation succeeds before going on.